# Google Form API - unable to retrieve a respondent email

Tags: node.js, google-forms, google-developers-console, google-forms-api

I am using Google Form API to create a sample project to create, update & get responses to a form.
I am using the following documentation for reference and understanding:
https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.responses
It mentions that a single response body (using response ID) includes the respondent email, but each time I trigger the API, the respondent email is undefined and hence does not get returned in the response body.
What am I doing wrong?

Please note I am not using the Apps Script. I am using the API in a node.js project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the respondent's email in the response body because the form is not set to collect them. By default, forms created using the api will not collect email information. This might be different for the node.js, but for the python integration of the Google Forms API, you can't automatically get the responder's email, and there isn't an option/param in the api to allow this.

There are two ways to "automatically" collect the emails. You can find these methods in the official Google how-to guides, but I'll write them in my own words to save you some time:

The first method is to create a form in the drive folder that will store all other forms you will create (e.g. "my_form.form" in /my/drive/root/MyForms/.). Open the form and in the settings tab, scroll all the way down to the "Defaults" section. Select "Collect email addresses by default". From now on, any form you create directly **in this folder** (/my/drive/root/my_forms/) **using the web ui** will automatically be set to collect emails. This does *not*, however, work if you use an api, even the Google Drive API, to create the form in that folder.

The second way (or the only way if you're not going to use the same folder every time) is to manually edit each form you create to collect them before you send it out. You'll need to go to the form in the drive webpage, scroll to "Responses" and then select "Collect email addresses". This is currently (as of the date I'm writing -- if that ever changes, someone please comment because it's driving me batty!) the only way to collect the email addresses with the responses. Once the button is selected, the response body from the api will properly contain the responder's email as described by the documentation you linked above. Maybe the next iteration of the Google Forms API will allow us to set this programmatically (*hint, hint!*), but until then, humans are still required in the workflow.

Head's up: if you forget to set the form to collect the email accounts before you send it out, changing the setting will only apply to all responses submitted *after* the change. You cannot retroactively add the emails without hunting down the responder and editing the response sheet manually.